# Changing a point in a list

Tags: c#

I've written a simple class, `point`, and I want to use it in a list.

In the list I have 3 points. If I print it:

```
for (int i = listOfPoint.Count -1; i >=0; i--)
{
    Console.WriteLine(listOfPoint[i].toString());
}
```

the output is:

```
(32, 10)
(33, 10)
(34, 10)
```

now, I want to do this:

```
for (int i = listOfPoint.Count -1; i > 0; i--)
{
    listOfPoint[i] = listOfPoint[i - 1];
}
```

after this - print:

```
(33, 10)
(34, 10)
(34, 10)
```

after this - I want to change the Y value of `listOfPoint[0]`, so:

```
listOfPoint[0].Y = 11;
```

print the list again and the output is:

```
(33, 10)
(34, 11)
(34, 11)
```

Why isn't the output:

```
(33, 10)
(34, 10)
(34, 11)
```

And how can I do it like this?

Comment: Post your `Point` class. And show us how you have created `listOfPoints`.

Comment: `listOfPoint[i] = listOfPoint[i-1]` doesn't create a new `Point` object. You have two elements referencing the same `Point` object.

Comment: You should probably make `Point` a `struct`, not a `class`. Or just use WinForms' built-in one if applicable.

Comment: You should understand the difference beween [Value Types and Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happen because you have two element of the array referencing the same object. This is due to pointers.

Try to do this to avoid the problem:

```
for (int i = listOfPoint.Count -1; i > 0; i--)
{
    //Pass the value not the pointer
    listOfPoint[i] = new Point(listOfPoint[i-1].X, listOfPoint[i-1].Y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your "move them up by one" (second for loop), listOfPoint[0] and listOfPoint[1] point to the same object.  To avoid this add this line:

```
listOfPoint[0] = new Point(listOfPoint[1].X, listOfPoint[1].Y);
```